# Javascript/JQuery prevent navigation totally inside an iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, jquery-events

I have a same domain page loaded inside an iframe (using sandbox attribute). I use the following code to prevent clicks (and all other elements) from navigating away form the page:

```
$('#preview_frame').contents().find('body *').off('click').click(
        function(event){
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    );
```

However it seems that other Javascript on the page is redirecting the navigation via `window.location.href` or `window.location.replace`.

I cannot change the code of the pages inside the iframe as they are proxied from other sites.

I tried using the iframe unload event without success.

I need to disable the ability to navigate inside the iframe no matter what/how it is done. I am not talking about top parent navigation which can be disabled with the sandbox attribute, I am talking about the navigation INSIDE the iframe itself.

Is it possible to accomplish that?

Comment: Using the `beforeunload` event could show the user a message before the navigation change occurs - but that does not work in all browsers/settings, specifically with an iframe you'd need to test and find out. If that's not an option, then you'll have to delve a little deeper into what's going on when those other scripts are changing the location, starting with what's it triggered by.

Comment: @CBroe unfortunately beforeunload event cannot cancel the url change.

Comment: Try delegating to the event listener to the document. Also it would not affect any non jquery event listeners or inline event listeners. There is no simple answer without examining the page code

Comment: @charlietfl my problem is that the content loaded inside the iframe comes from virtually any online website so even if I optimized and handled a specific page, another page can contain other method to navigate. My goal is to disable the possibility of ANY navigation regardless of what's causing it if that is doable in Javascript?

Comment: There is no *"one size fits all"* answer

Comment: @charlietfl so you think there is no way to cancel a url change in Javascript?

Comment: For straightforward links it will be no problem by preventing default. Any other redirect approaches used though would require investigation

Comment: @charlietfl I totally agree with you. As I wrote in the question, the script is changing the window.location.href . That's what i need to interrupt and prevent somehow.

Comment: For starters remove all `onclick`. Beyond that you need more specifics, there is no single method and issue becomes more complex if any asynchronously loaded content

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct. Remove the sandbox attribute if the page inside iframe is from same domain. Hope it will solve the problem.

Sandbox attribute always treats contents as unique origin.

Comment: The code I posted to prevent links clicks works. I already know that. The question is asking how to prevent window.location.href events or better yet any URL change request.

Comment: I don't think we can prevent iframe from location changing if location change is triggered without any event.